# Performance problem Ubuntu 20.04 when sharing screen with discord 0.0.10 and gaming

Tags: multiple-monitors, steam, performance, 20.04, cpu-load

I have a performance problem when I play a game on Steam Proton and sharing the screen on discord 0.0.10.

An example here, I am playing Monster Hunter World and show FPS on-screen and it shows 70 FPS in avg.

At the same time, I'm talking to my friends on Discord's app version 0.0.10. Everything is fine.

One moment later, I want to share my screen with Monster Hunter world on it.

At this moment, My CPU is 100% on the process, and the FPS on the game show 50 but feel 15. The stream on discord feels lagging for me and my friend and my game also feel lagging.

Keyboard inputs are ignored by Ubuntu and I must push many times a key before having an interaction.

This is the same thing if I open firefox and have some ads on the web page while I'm playing.

My build is not the bottleneck here:

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
AMD Ryzen 5 3600 OC 4.2Ghz
MSI X570 Gaming Plus - Bios=7C37vA7
Nvidia RTX 2080 Super (Nvidia Proprietary Driver 440.64)
16GB DDR4 3200Mhz
SSD 1To Corsair Force MP600 M.2 PCIe 4.0 (Ubuntu 20.04 installed on it and all apps and games also)
Dual screen (Left 1080p, right 1440p Main)

If someone can resolve this problem or tell me what's wrong, it may be Discord...?

Answer (score 0):

in my case happened something similar, got it "fixed" by turning off hardware aceleration in discord appareance settings. Now discord got from 30% to 50% of my cpu iddling when sharing screen, but SOMEHOW the OS and videos/games that i share lags less than before. lets say before my fps got from 30 to 12 when sharing screen, now it gets from 30 to 20, so its somehow better, but not as good as windows perfomance, wich i got installed in the same laptop and lags way less, lets say it gets from 35fps to 28.